Nginx 404 not found when refreshing, also with try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
I cannot figure out how to reslove the 404 error while refreshing.
here is related part of my config:

server {
    server_name    example.com;
     location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.x.y:5000; # Proxy requests to Node web server on port 8000
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.x.y:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    server_name    example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}


I have also tried to use the try_files inside  " location / " section but did not work or maybe I did it wrong.
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

my index.html is serverd in web server in this path:
/home/ubuntu/web_server/public/index.html

which mounts through a docker container like this
   volumes:
      - ./nginx_data:/etc/nginx/conf.d       # Nginx configurations
      - /etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/  # Certificates for https


Here is the updated nginx config
server {
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        # Serve the index.html file for all unmatched routes
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        # Proxy pass to the backend server
        proxy_pass http://192.168.x.y:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.x.y:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

This will make your SPA always loads and lets the client-side router handle the navigation.
sudo systemctl restart nginx

Above command to restart nginx
